# How can I label an event happening "every Monday" using HTML5 microdata

Tags: html, date, microdata

I'm trying to use [HTML5 microdata](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/176035?hl=en) to label events in my website. The problem is that my events have a weekday frequency (for example, "Every Monday from 20:00 to 22:00 hs") and according to the [HTML5 microdata specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/microdata/master/) start-time should be specified using the [ISO 8601 date format](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date) but I cannot figure out how to specify "Every Monday" using ISO 8601.

Is it possible to do that? Is there an alternative to label weekday events?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this proposal to schema.org about improving Events markup: [EventSchemaUpdate](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/EventSchemaUpdate), [pdf](http://www.w3.org/wiki/images/d/db/Events-proposalforupdatedschemav2.pdf)

One of the changes is support for recurring events:

> **Recurring events**
>
> We address the desire for startDate and endDate pairs to be repeatable
>   (i.e. for repeating events that are described by enumeration rather
>   than ISO8601 repetition rules). This is accomplished by allowing any
>   Event to carry an 'occurrenceEvent' property whose value is another
>   Event entity. Effectively this makes a single general Event
>   description serve as a kind of template that references specific
>   occurances which are then typically described using at least startDate
>   and endDate, but potentially any other Eventoriented vocabulary.
>   (Aside: this is similar to the Good Relations ProductModel
>   construction, i.e. http://schema.org/ProductModel, which also uses a
>   prototypical instance to capture templatelike repetition). If a single
>   event has multiple listed pairs of start and end dates (via
>   occurenceEvent), it means that the event repeats on each of these
>   occasions.
>
> For example:
>
> 1) Event repeats every Monday in January 2012.
>
> ```
> <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"> ...
> <span itemprop="occurenceEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
> <time itemprop=”startDate” datetime=”201212”></
> time>
> </span>
> <span itemprop="occurenceEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
> <time itemprop=”startDate” datetime=”2012116”></
> time>
> </span>
> <span itemprop="occurenceEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
> <time itemprop=”startDate” datetime=”2012123”></
> time>
> </span>
> <span itemprop="occurenceEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
> <time itemprop=”startDate” datetime=”2012130”></
> time>
> </span>
> </div>
> ```
>
> 2) Event repeats every weekend in Febuary 2012.
>
> ```
> <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"> ...
> <span itemprop="occurenceEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
> <time itemprop=”startDate” datetime=”201223”></
> time>
> <time itemprop=”endDate” datetime=”201225”></
> time>
> </span>
> <span itemprop="occurenceEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
> <time itemprop=”startDate” datetime=”2012210”></
> time>
> <time itemprop=”endDate” datetime=”2012212”></
> time>
> </span>
> <span itemprop="occurenceEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
> <time itemprop=”startDate” datetime=”2012217”></
> time>
> <time itemprop=”endDate” datetime=”2012219”></
> time>
> </span>
> <span itemprop="occurenceEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
> <time itemprop=”startDate” datetime=”2012224”></
> time>
> <time itemprop=”endDate” datetime=”2012226”></
> time>
> </span>
> </div>
> ```
>
> This method of markup is verbose but conceptually simple and can
>   represent any combination of date ranges. Note that there is no way to
>   specify that a recurrence occurs forever (i.e. “every Thursday at
>   8pm”) since each instance must be listed explicitly. This is by
>   design, to prevent stale, incorrect data from a web page that is no
>   longer maintained from existing forever into the future.
>
> Note that a recurring event (i.e. a Photography class offered three
>   days in a row) is different than a multiday event (i.e. a 3day music
>   festival) though the difference can sometimes be blurry (consider art
>   exhibitions or broadway shows). ISO 8601 repeating intervals are also
>   supported to allow a more succinct representation of very regular
>   recurrence. This is not a change to the actual schema but rather a
>   clarification to how the field may be used to explicitly call out
>   support for this type of recurrence.  Repeated instances of ISO 8601
>   repeating intervals are possible but only where the resulting events
>   do not overlap and are discouraged.

Not sure about using it in this very design right now (there is a risk of some changes). But you can follow the discussion and participate  at [maillist](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 microdata spec only supports single dates, not recurring events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if it's possible to label recurring events with some alternative like  Microformats or RDFa?

Comment: The standard for communicating scheduled events like this is [ICalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) (e.g, `.ics` files). There's a format for embedding that in web pages ([hCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCalendar)), but, so far as I know, support is limited.